# Python Dash - Keep columns when scrolling

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard, tabular

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from dash import Dash, dash_table

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['test', 'tset'] * 120,
    'B': ['a', 'b', 'c'] * 80,
})

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

When I scroll down, the column names disappear. How can I fix the column names? I still want to be able to read the column names when scrolling down.

Answer (score 1):

You can get more information from dash.plotly.com/datatable/height

For your question:

```
fixed_rows={‘headers’:True}
```

Comment: Sorry this does not really help me. I already found this solution but it splits the tabular in half, giving me just the upper 16 rows. There is also a footer as in this image: https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/business7/uploads/plot/optimized/2X/7/74ccd6e118e9286e1d9d0b5f07e5f71973f2466f_2_1380x908.png

Comment: Could you please adapt my code so you can see what I mean or post your complete code if it works?

Comment: Your image is confusing where is the table in the image, how it splits the table in half?

Comment: The image is from the web and not from my project. Including the line of code diana18 mentioned will give me a footer which consumes about half of the bottom space within the browser. The upper half is allocated by the table.